# Divide given value by .style.width in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would need to divide a value given by .style.width function in Javascript.
My code looks like this:

```
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    var i;

    var v = x[0].style.width;
```

In variable 'v' I have some value in pixels, e.g. 200px width.
I would need to divide this value by 2 to get 100px.
But this formula doesn't work:
`var v = x[0].style.width / 2;`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: `var v = parseInt(x[0].style.width) / 2;`

Comment: Maybe `var v = x[0].clientWidth / 2 + "px";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width` will be string. Convert it to number before dividing. This example uses [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get actual width of a dom element

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('test');
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
const widthInteger = parseInt(compStyles.width, 10);
const halfWidth = widthInteger / 2;
console.log(halfWidth)
```

```css
.test {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class='test' id='test'></div>
```